# why doesn't !important work in my css?

Tags: css, vue.js

Here is my code.http://codepen.io/xueyan123/pen/oWMNNa when I try to use !important in my css to cover the background-color to blue, it is still red. why is that?

```
#app{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  border:1px #ff0000 solid
}

.active{
  background-color:#0000ff;!important
}
```

In my case, .active and #app refers to the same DOM element.

Comment: Get rid of `;` you want `background-color:#0000ff !important;` . Better still avoid `important!` if you can.

Comment: semicolon should be after `!important`

Comment: active class is not added to the element

Comment: if u remove !important also it is working ,is there any reason to add !important,new Vue({ el:"#app", data:{ message:"hello", isActive:false },so only on click you will get blue background

Comment: really? If I remove the !important, it doesn't work at all. Cause compared to #app, the .active class's weight is lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Wrong - background-color:#0000ff; !important

Right - background-color:#0000ff !important ;
```